# ASP.Net Core LogLevel not working

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core

I'm having trouble getting the logger to work like i want it to. I've set the loglevel to warning, but the console window is still bloated with info logs.

I've provided some examples below, nothing extra is configured in Startup.cs or Program.cs.

I'm happy to provide more information if needed.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "ConnectionString"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false, 
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Logging example:

```
public class DishRepository : IDishRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<DishRepository> _logger;

    public DishRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, ILogger<DishRepository> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Dish> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("GetAll was called");

            return _context.Dishes
                .Include(d => d.Category)
                .Include(d => d.DishIngredients)
                .ThenInclude(di => di.Ingredient)
                .Include(d => d.PizzaType).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Failed to get all dishes: {e}");
            return Enumerable.Empty<Dish>();
        }

    }
}
```

When i run my program via VisualStudio i get this:

[image: dotnet console]

--------This Works--------

I found the example below at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x it works, but I don't understand why this works and not the appsettings.json example above.

appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"Debug": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "PizzeriaAngular": "Warning",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information" 
  }
},
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug"
}
```

}

Program.cs still looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 41):

There are two config files appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json. And system use it in development mode.

Comment: This was super helpful when trying to get the "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" and i had checked their sample project multiple times but it ended being hidden in the appsettings.Development.json as was suggested here cudos thanks for the direction.

Comment: After wasting 2 hours pulling my head hair, this is it! Completely missed the Development.json part. Much thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This code work for me (**NetCore 2.x**)
in class **Startup.cs** in method  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
services.AddLogging(builder =>
        {
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
            builder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Error);
            builder.AddFilter("Engine", LogLevel.Warning);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using another logging provider, like **NLog**, then the "Logging" appsettings for Microsoft will not work.

For **NLog**, you have to set the minimum logging level in the nlog.config:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="default" />
```

Comment: See also:  https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter